# Angular 12 how to load external URL content

Tags: angular, http-headers, httpclient

There is an external URL, how can I load its HTML content into div?

The template:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlData">
</div>
```

The .ts file,
class variables and constructor:

```
  requestHeaders = new Headers();
  httpOptions = new Object();
  htmlContent$: Observable<string>;
  htmlData: SafeHtml = 'Loading...';
  private googleScholarURL = "https://scholar.google.com";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
```

The ngOnInit:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.requestHeaders.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    this.requestHeaders.append('mode', 'no-cors');
    this.httpOptions = {
      headers: this.requestHeaders,
      responseType: 'text'
    }
    this.htmlContent$ = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.googleScholarURL,  this.httpOptions );

    this.htmlContent$.subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.htmlData = result;
      }
    });
  }
```

I got the error:
*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://scholar.google.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

What did I wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove all those headers from the client to start with and then add proper CORS headers on the server side.

Comment: MieOne, I did not understand you, what server side?

Answer (score -1):

You would need to use a middleware like nodejs and curl the request, then send the response back to angular via proxy. Try the request in postman, if it returns the html, then this method I speak of will work. Checkout node-libcurl for making such a request. you would wrap this in a route handler node. Let me know if you have any other questions.

This is pretty much standard Cors policy restriction.

Comment: Hi Judson, Is there a way to handle it below angular, without an external server?
I tried to follow the following (Method 1) but I unable to add proxyConfig below architect/options in angular.json

Comment: This one:
https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-proxy-configuration-to-handle-cors-issue/

Comment: Yes along with the proxy config setup. I’ll provide and example…

Comment: Judson, I appreciate it if you show me a code example, please.